# Javascript factory function not working properly

Tags: javascript, function

according to the tutorial i'm watching this code is supposed to return "John Doe." Presently, it only returns "[object, Object]", what am I doing wrong?

```
<p id="para"></p>

function createPerson(firstName, lastName) {
    return {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        getFullName: function() {
            return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
        }
    };
}

var person = createPerson("John", "Doe");


document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = person;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: you have to set a string to innerHTML: `document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = person.getFullName();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object key function was missing .you are only post with object not mention with function in object .So mention the function name of object key.

like this

```
 1. person.getFullName();// for function call
 2. person.firstName 
 3. person.lastName
```

For more understanding [refer this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

```js
function createPerson(firstName, lastName) {
  return {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    getFullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  };
}

var person = createPerson("John", "Doe");


document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = person.getFullName();
```

```html
<p id="para"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function createPerson(firstName, lastName) {
  return {
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    getFullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
  };
}
```

var person = createPerson("John", "Doe");

> it only returns "[object, Object]"

because person is an object there

```
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = person;
```

if you want to print firstname

```
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = person.firstName
```

if you wnat to print lastName

```
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = person.lastName
```

if you want to print fullname

```
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = person.getFullName()
```

not the last one you have to invoke the function .